# FileNotFoundException in File.AppendAllText

Tags: c#, io

I was reading `File.AppendAllText` method from msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx

I saw they have listed `FileNotFoundException` to possible exceptions list for the method but according to there description about method on the same page

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. 
>   If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, 
>   writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

this part

> If the file does not exist, this method creates a file

it seems this exception can never be thrown for this method.

Comment: I suppose its possible that it may be unable to create the file due to security reasons or similar

Comment: @Sayse There's a different exception for that.

Comment: The FileNotFoundException  is in case the directory not exist

Comment: @Sayse There's `UnauthorizedAccessException` for that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - ah ok ^.^

Comment: @OneManCrew `DirectoryNotFoundException`

Comment: @PLB Yup; just tested that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at (say) Mono's implementation (which is compatible with Microsoft's), all `File.AppendAllText` ends up doing (argument checks aside) is creating a `StreamWriter` with your path and calling a `Write` on that object.

Neither the used constructor nor the method are listed anywhere to throw a `FileNotFoundException`, as far as I can tell, so it *might* be a documentation error.

Comment: Could be a documentation error, yeah; I can't see any way that exception should be thrown from that method.

Answer (score 0):

This thread may be old, but the correct answer given above by One-man-crew was ignored by others.
The fact is that the FileNotFoundException is not a typo error. It exists, and I get it.
The reason is in the exception message as follows: 
"Could not find part of the path". 
As described, the File.AppendAllText will open the **file if it does not exist**, but it must have a **valid path**.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The problem was that the path I had provided was not available.

AppendAllLines or AppendAllText does not create the path, it only creates the file.

To solve this, I created the path using System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Folder Path"]).

Then I used the AppendAllLines and AppendAllText methods.