# File.AppendAllText throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, exception, add-on

I am working on Internet explorer add-on, I wrote a dll that attached to the browaswer, Ihave some event, inside of ot I am writing to some text file with `File.AppendAllText`, this throws `FileNotFoundException`, I am using `AppendAllText` in other places in my code, and there if the file is not exist it creates a new file, my question is why this exception throwen and how can I avoid that.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626924/12550657) answer, but it doesnt say how to avoid the error (i.e to write the file without getting this exception), also didn't understad that this is a "documentation error"

Here file fath:

```
static string assem = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
static string logPath = Path.Combine(assem, "Log.log");
```

Here the line that thows the error:

```
File.AppendAllText(logPath, "some text" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Here the exception:

[image]

Comment: Read the second answer and post your code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630895/4123703 Because your path might be invalid in that case..or something else. Can't tell if there is no detail.

Comment: The command `AppendAllText` adds text to an already existing file. When you compile the bin\Debug folder content is deleted. Are you creating the file before trying to add content to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably IE blocks the extension to write to a local file, try to uncheck the "Protected mode" int the browser

Tools --> Internet Options --> Security --> unckeck "Enable Protected Mode"

Answer (score 0):

The exception type is a bit misleading; in some ways it'd be better to throw a `ArgumentException` perhaps.  The reason you're seeing this exception is the path you're supplying is not a valid file path (either it contains an invalid character or it's >255 characters).

Inspect the value of the path at this point in the code in a debugger, open up a command prompt and issue the following command to see if you can write to that path:

```
echo "Testing creating a file at this path" > "C:\Path\To\Your\File.txt"
```

I'll hasten a guess that the path contains a directory which does not exist (e.g. your path is `C:\Path\To\Your\File.txt` but the `Path` directory does not contain a `To` subdirectory).

Comment: `IExtonsionsTests` is the name of existing folder (with a typo), see how the code gets this path, it goes where the project is, the path is valid

Comment: I wrote in cmd `echo "Testing creating a file at this path" > "D:\IExtonsionsTests\1\bin\Debug\Log.log"` it write the text to the file

Comment: Temporarily hard-code that path into your program and see if it works.  If it doesn't keep going 'up' a directory until it works, e.g. next try writing to `D:\IExtonsionsTests\1\bin\Log.log`.  Can you write the file to the root of your D drive?